# Text area rows should be displayed with XML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small requirement that i want to read text area rows and need to display it like xml format.
I tried with following code, it successfully gives the alert with xml structure.
we have to display the entire rows with xml format. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#saveImgID").click(function(){
              var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Rowsets DateCreated=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" EndDate=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" StartDate=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" Version=\"14.0 SP4 Patch 0 (Nov 22, 2013)" +">";
              var xmlEnd = "</Rowset></Rowsets>";
        var lines = $('#fileContent1').val().split(/\n/);
     var texts = []
     for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
           if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
             texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
          }
     }
     for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {         
        alert(xmlStart+"<Rowset><Row><Line>"+texts[i]+"</Line></Row>"+xmlEnd);
      }
   });     
});
```

I have to display like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Rowsets DateCreated="2014-11-20T16:41:17" EndDate="2014-11-20T16:41:17" StartDate="2014-11-20T16:41:17" Version="14.0 SP4 Patch 0 (Nov 22, 2013)>
    <Rowset>
    <Row>
        <Line>101,abc,andy,1000</Line>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Line>202,abc,sachin,2000</Line>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Line>303,abc,smith,3000</Line>
    </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Here is the fiddle [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hy91m3tr/)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get what is the issue you have

Comment: Display it where? In the alert?

Comment: @ PeterKA yes.. I have to display the values in the alert , as of now displaying one by one... I want only rows will be repeating and displayed xml structure as mentioned in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build your XML inside the loop and alert outside of it :
http://jsfiddle.net/hy91m3tr/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#saveImgID").click(function(){
    var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Rowsets DateCreated=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" EndDate=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" StartDate=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" Version=\"14.0 SP4 Patch 0 (Nov 22, 2013)" +">";
    var xmlEnd = "</Rowset></Rowsets>";
    var xml;
    var lines = $('#fileContent1').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = []
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
        texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
      }
    }
    xml = xmlStart + "<Rowset>";
    for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {         
      xml += "<Row><Line>"+texts[i]+"</Line></Row>";
    }
    xml += xmlEnd;
    alert(xml);
  });     
});
```

Comment: Yes... I did small mistake, Thanks for the answer.. It is working fine.

Comment: @Rajasekhar do not add <Rowset> in each iteration.

Comment: @Rajasekhar Cool ! Oh and as **suchit** points it out, I made a mistake myself in the code above, the `<Rowset>` is misplaced, I'll edit my answer right away !

Answer (score 1):

what you exactly need is to consturct it in single valriable then alert:try like this

```
var totalstr = xmlStart+"<Rowset>";
     for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {         
        totalstr = totalstr +"<Row><Line>"+texts[i]+"</Line></Row>";
      }
     totalstr=totalstr+xmlEnd;
     alert(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#saveImgID").click(function(){
        var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Rowsets DateCreated=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" EndDate=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" StartDate=\"2014-11-20T16:41:17\" Version=\"14.0 SP4 Patch 0 (Nov 22, 2013)" +">";
        var xmlEnd = "</Rowset></Rowsets>";
        var lines = $('#fileContent1').val().split(/\n/);
        var texts = []
        for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
                texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
            }
        }
        var wholeXML = xmlStart + "\n<Rowsets>\n\t<Rowset>";
        for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {          
            wholeXML += "\n\t\t<Row>\n\t\t\t<Line>"+texts[i]+"</Line>\n\t\t</Row>";
        }
        wholeXML += xmlEnd;
        alert( wholeXML )
    });     
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/hy91m3tr/3/)